# Fade In Out javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Sorry But just can't find the similar question. So the problem is  I couldn't find the way to make the message fade in out after every tic-tac-toe game. It works only first time, and then disappears.
Here is a link with the full code: http://codepen.io/Y-Taras/pen/rrkKWz
I tried to add a

   `footer.className = "";`
 But this time the message as was expected didn't appear at all.
The code is too long, so here 's an abstract concerning the problem:

```
<footer></footer>
```

And css:

```
footer.fade {
animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeinout {
0%, 100% {opacity: 0;
}
50% {opacity: 1;
}}
```

And JS

```
 function makeMove() {
    if (game.winner(board) === "x") {
        footer.innerHTML = "The Winner is X";
        footer.className = "fade";
        restartGame();
        return;
    } else if (game.winner(board) === "o") {
        footer.innerHTML = "The Winner is O";
        footer.className = "fade";
        restartGame();
        return;
    } else if (game.winner(board) === true) {
        footer.innerHTML = "It's a draw";
        footer.className = "fade";
        restartGame();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Adding the same classname over and over does not trigger the animation as it doesn't even update the DOM when the class is the same as it was

Comment: It's better to Make JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is a `transition` between two states (class). For this to work, you should change the class name to something else otherwise it is not triggered.

CSS:

```
footer.show { opacity: 1; transition: opacity 4s linear; }
footer.hide { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 4s linear; }
```

JS:

```
function makeMove() {
if (game.winner(board) === "x") {
    footer.innerHTML = "The Winner is X";
    footer.className = "show";
    ...

function restartGame() {
    footer.className = "hide";
    ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work, cause   function restartGame() immediately change class to hide.

Comment: after adding a delay it worked but not exactly as it supposed to work

        setTimeout(hide, 4000);
        function hide() {
            footer.className = "hide";
        }